# Plotting Rsquare objects from three RFE

Tags: r

I have created the following three RFE types in R using the caret package:

```
lmresults = rfe(twoHoursDaily[,1:12], twoHoursDaily[,13], sizes = c(1:12), rfeControl = control)

treeBagresults = rfe(twoHoursDaily[,1:12], twoHoursDaily[,13], sizes = c(1:12), rfeControl = control)

RForestresults = rfe(twoHoursDaily[,1:12], twoHoursDaily[,13], sizes = c(1:12), rfeControl = control)
```

I need to plot the Rsquares for all three on one plot, but I dont know how to access the Rsquare object for each RFE. I can plot the Rsquare of one as follows:

```
plot(treeBagresults, type = c("g","o"), metric = "Rsquared")
```

but how do I access the Rsquare object for each so I can make the vector pr DF needed for plotting all three?

Comment: that was exactly what I needed. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `rfe` will be a `list`.  We need to extract the `list` element that has the Rsquared objects.  In order to understand the structure of the output, we can use `str(lmresults)`.  From there, get the `results` element

```
 lmresults$results[["Rsquared"]]
```

Similarly, for the other objects.